# Xcode Detect Certain Characters In TextField

Tags: xcode, text, character, textfield

Is there a way for me to detect if there is a certain character (,) in a textfield, and if so display and alert? I do not have any code because I dont really know where to start :). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a textfield and you want to get its value, use this:

```
NSString *myString = textField.text;
```

Now you can check if `myString` contains it:

```
if ([myString rangeOfString:@","].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"Not found!");
} else {
  NSLog(@"Display and Alert!");
}
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you so much for your help!